# pgfplots how to reduce compilation time

Tags: pgfplots, compiling

My code for creating a figure takes forever to compile

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
            xtick = {0,50,...,200},
            ytick = {0,50,...,200},
            ztick = {0,50,...,300},
            xlabel = $U_A$, ylabel = $U_B$, zlabel = $S$,
            zlabel style={rotate=-90},
            ticklabel style = {font = \scriptsize},
            colormap/cool
            ]
            \addplot3 [surf, shader=interp, domain=0.001:200, samples=60] 
            { ln((200!/(x!*(200-x)!))*(200!/(y!*(200-y)!))) };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is obviously because I use large numbers. Any ideas on how can I reduce compilation time?

Comment: I'd say calculate your values in a csv with a programming language (e.g. Python) and plot the results. You'll have precision issues with TeX anyway, 200! is not small and a floating point implementation will have pretty limited precision. Btw. any particular reason why you start at `0.001` instead of `0` (note that 0! == 1)? Also note that most factorial implementations work on integer values (`pgf` will silently floor them, so `3.9!` will yield 6).